# How to sent the JWT from login route to the upcoming requests

Tags: express, jwt, authorization

Hello i sent a JWT http only cookie from a flask server to my express. When i hit on postman the request with the JWT authentication it's works so i suppose that my backend development has not a problem. My `/login` endpoint is like this:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
 axios.post(`...../login`, {
  email: req.body.email, 
  password: req.body.password
 }, { headers: {
 ........
const token = access_token_cookie.substring(jwt_start, jwt_end);
res.locals.token = token;
next()
return res.json({
  success: response.data.success,
   .......
})
  }).catch( (err)  => {return res.status(400).json({
    success: false,
   message: 'Could not process the form.'
})})
},addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware);

module.exports = router;
```

My `addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware` is a function that i want to "save" my JWT

```
const addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  if (res.locals && res.locals.token) {
    req.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${res.locals.token}`;
  }
  console.log('req.headers :', req.headers['Authorization'])
  next();
};

module.exports = addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware;
```

When i `console.log` it i can see my JWT. Now i want to sent it to my other upcoming `requests`. I am using a middleware like

```
router.route('/Organizations').post(addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware,asyncMiddleware(allControllers.Organizations))
```

I observe that when i do this my `console.log` inside the `addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware` becomes undefined. So i want to use the JWT from this function `addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware` inside my endpoint

```
exports.Organizations = async (req, res, next) => {.....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store your token in local storage

```
const token = access_token_cookie.substring(jwt_start, jwt_end)
localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify({ accesstoken: token }))
```

then whenever you want to make a request, add it inside your config object

```
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accesstoken"))

const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: token,
  },
}

const response = await axios.post(
  `${URL}`,
  data,
  config
)
```

and then access it in your addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware middleware like that?

```
const addAuthTokenToHeaderMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('Authorization')
  console.log('token', token)
  //...
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is i want to avoid, to save my JWT to local storage (for security reasons). Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: What is your front end environment?

Comment: My front end enviroment is reactJS